# When can a function not be factored?

Tags: factoring

Are there any general conditions under which a function involving $n$ unknowns cannot be factored into a product of $n$ terms each of which contains only one of the unknowns?

For example, $xy$ can be factored into $x$ and $y$ but we cannot factor $1/(1+xy)$ into a product of terms, each of which only contains $x$ or $y$ but not both.

Besides looking at these functions on a case by case basis, I am wondering if anyone knows any general sufficient conditions to determine whether the factorization can definitely $\textit{not}$ hold.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that $1/(1+xy)$ cannot be factored into the form $f(x)g(y)$ where $f(x)$ contain infinitely many terms and $g(y)$ also contain infinitely many terms?

Comment: In a sense that $f$ is series in variable $x$ and $g$ is series in variable $y$.

Comment: That might be possible, but I would like to restrict attention to a finite number of terms. Specifically, if there are $n$ unknowns, then conditions under which we can get $n$ terms.

Comment: I think we are using the term "terms" in two different senses, I am saying that the terms $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ could be infinite series and in that sense I am using the word "terms" to denote powers (positive and/or negative) of variable $x$ and $y$.

Comment: And I have an idea on how could it be proven that general enough (for me, would it be for you I do not know) class of functions in $n$ variables can be factored into $n$ terms, or cannot, depending on whether the intuition is right or wrong, but there are some elements of the proof that I, at the moment, do not see how to handle.

Comment: That's ok - what is your idea?

Comment: Will you buy me one white chocolate which has coconut in itself if I tell you?

Comment: depends on how awesome your answer is...

Comment: @AntePaladin: $1/(1+xy)$ can't be factored as $f(x)g(y)$: putting $x=0$ gives $f(0)g(y) = 1$ for all $y$. And stop that flirting, you two!

Answer (score 3):

Nice question. Turns out to have a pretty nice answer too.

**Theorem:** Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. There exist $g,h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$ if and only if for all $x,x',y,y'\in\mathbb R$ we have
$f(x,y)f(x',y')=f(x,y')f(x',y)$.

*proof:* Suppose $g,h$ exists such that $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$. Then 
$$f(x,y)f(x',y')=g(x)h(y)g(x')h(y') = g(x)h(y')g(x')h(y) = f(x,y')f(x',y)$$

Now suppose that $f$ satisfies $f(x,y)f(x',y')=f(x,y')f(x',y)$ for all $x,x',y,y'$. If $f$ is identically $0$ we can just define $g$ and $h$ to be zero too so this case is trivial. If $f$ is not identically $0$ then find $a,b\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(a,b)\neq 0$. Then define $g(x) = f(x,b)$ and $h(y) = \frac{f(a,y)}{f(a,b)}$. Now we see that
$$g(x)h(y) = f(x,b)\frac{f(a,y)}{f(a,b)} = f(x,y)\qquad\square$$

This can be generalized to higher dimensions but the condition is a little trickier to write down. The condition becomes
$$f(x_1,\ldots x_n)f(x_1',\ldots,x_n')^{n-1} = \prod_{i-1}^n f(x_1',\ldots, x_{i-1}',x_i,x_{i+1}',\ldots,x_n')$$